# waiting observable subscribe inside foreach with forkJoin

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to populate an array in my component called conventions which is an array of convention.

Each organization has a list of contracts, and each contract has a convention id, with this id i got the convention.

I use getOrganizationForUser to get current organization and then get the list of contract. 
Then i use the convention id from contract to call the second API to get the convention.

Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
public getOrganizationForUser(): Observable<Organization> {
        return this.httpClient
            .get<Organization>(`${c.serviceBaseUrl.sp}/organizationByUser`)
            .pipe(catchError((err, source) => this.responseHandler.onCatch(err, source)));
    }

 public getById(id: number) {
        return this.httpClient
            .get<Convention>(`${c.serviceBaseUrl.sp}/conventions/` + id)
            .pipe(catchError((err, source) => this.responseHandler.onCatch(err, source)));
    }

ngOnInit() {
    this.OrganizationService.getOrganizationForUser().subscribe((organization: Organization) => {
        organization.contracts.forEach((contract) => {
            this.conventionService.getById(contract.conventionId).subscribe((convention: Convention) => {
                this.conventions.push(convention);
            })
        })
   })
}
```

I understand that I can create an array of observables, and use `Observable.forkJoin()` to wait for all these async calls to finish but I want to be able to define the subscribe callback 
function for each of the calls since I need a reference to the process. Any ideas on how I can go about approaching this issue?

i tried with this function but always is return understand

```
getTasksForEachProcess(): Observable<Array<any>> {
    let tasksObservables = this.organizationService.getOrganizationForUser().pipe(map((organization: Organization) => {
        organization.contractOrganizations.map(contract => {
            return this.conventionService.getById(contract.conventionId).subscribe(convention =>
                this.conventions.push(convention)
            )
        });
    })
    );
    return forkJoin(tasksObservables);
};

ngOnInit() {
    this.getTasksForEachProcess().subscribe(item => {
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I am not sure of what your are really trying to achieve, since I do not understand what you mean by

> I want to be able to define the subscribe callback function for each
>   of the calls since I need a reference to the process

Anyways, in a situation like the one you describe, I would do something like this

```
public getOrganizationForUser(): Observable<Organization> {
        return this.httpClient
            .get<Organization>(`${c.serviceBaseUrl.sp}/organizationByUser`)
            .pipe(catchError((err, source) => this.responseHandler.onCatch(err, source)));
    }

 public getById(id: number) {
        return this.httpClient
            .get<Convention>(`${c.serviceBaseUrl.sp}/conventions/` + id)
            .pipe(catchError((err, source) => this.responseHandler.onCatch(err, source)));
    }

ngOnInit() {
    const obsOfObservables = this.OrganizationService.getOrganizationForUser()
    .pipe(
       map(organization => organization.contracts),
       map(contracts => contracts.map(contract => this.conventionService.getById(contract.conventionId)))
    );

    obsOfObservables
    .pipe(
       switchMap(conventionObservables => forkJoin(conventionObservables))
    )
    .subscribe(
       conventions => { // do stuff with conventions }
    )
}
```

The key points here are the following.

Via `getOrganizationForUser()` you get an Observable which emits the Organization. The first thing you do you transform the object emitted by the Observable into an Array of contracts with the first `map` operator.

The second `map` operator transforms the Array of contracts into an Array of Observables of conventions. To perform this transformation we use the `map` method of Array within the `map` operator of Observable. This may be a bit confusing, but it is worth understanding.

If we stop here, what we have is `obsOfObservables`, i.e. an Observable which emits an Array of Observables.

We then pass the Array of Observables emitted by `obsOfObservables` to the `forkJoin` function, which in itself returns an Observable. Since we actually interested in what is notified by the Observable returned by `forkJoin`, i.e. we are interested in the conventions, then we need to *switch* from the first Observable to the second one, and this is done via `switchMap` operator.

The net result is an Observable which returns an Array of conventions. Consider that the constant `obsOfObservables` has been added as an attempt to clarify the reasoning and it is *totally unnecessary* (as Barney Panofsky would say).

I have not simulated the whole thing, so I hope I have not inserted mistakes, but more or less this is the thought process I would use in this case.

Last note, be generally suspicious when you have `subscribe` within `subscibe`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Picci's logic in thinking through his answer.  Here is a slight variation to what he proposed, though like him I have not rigorously tested this and there may be some errors.

The logic to this is that what you ultimately want is an array of convention, and producing an array from observables is what 'zip' does.   So here is the flow:

- get an organization, then create a stream of observables out of the `organization.contracts` array using rxjs' `from`.
- each item in that stream will be a contract which will then be transformed (using `map`) into a convention based on and API lookup using the `contract.conventionId` property.
- this whole resulting stream of observables of conventions will finally be transformed back into an array by the wrapping zip, and delivered as an observable that can be subscribed to resulting in the wanted array of conventions.

Here is the code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    zip( this.OrganizationService.getOrganizationForUser()
        .pipe(
            map((organization: Organization) => 
                from(organization.contracts).pipe(
                    map(contract => this.conventionService.getById(contract.conventionId))
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .subscribe((conventions: Convention[]) => this.conventions = conventions)
}
```